# How to send activation email to user in spring framework?

Tags: spring, email

I want to send activation email to user, when they sign up my website, they will receive an email to verify their account activation request. Can you tell me some idea do that? 
I'm using Spring Framework to build my website.
Thank a lot :)

Comment: What did you try? Did you do a search on Google?

Comment: I've just try follow this tutorial http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mail.html. So i didn't any idea to process when user click link active in email?
Can u help me?

Comment: **It's not a tutorial.** It's a reference on how to use E-mail in spring. Do you even have a working user registration service that actually registers users in a database? Not just sending a mail like the docs show.

Comment: @vheln: do not use Spring 2.0 tutorials, use Spring 3.x tutorials/reference/docu

Answer (score 0):

Spring has no build in "Double Opt In" functionality. You need to implement them by your own.

What you can use is:

- Use Spring Mail support for sending the email
- Use Spring JBCD or Spring JPA Support or Spring Data JPA for storing the activation key that is send with the email in some database.
- Use Spring MVC for the frontend which use the user to interact with